# WebService returned a SOAP Fault: INVALID_SESSION_ID: This session is not valid for use with the API (async job)

Tags: metadata-api, asynchronous, session-id

I've take a look at a bunch of similar questions on stackexcahnge, but they weren't helpful. Here is the short explanation of the problem:

- We have a managed package with MetadataService class
- On one user's org in ASYNC jobs only request to Metadata API fails with `System.CalloutException: Web service callout failed: WebService returned a SOAP Fault: INVALID_SESSION_ID: This session is not valid for use with the API`
- The user is System Administrator with API Enabled = true and Apex REST Services = true
- Future method is run from @RestResource
- In sync context listMetadata works fine with this user token; in async - createMetadata fails with the error listed above

**What could have possibly gone wrong**? With other organizations and standard System Administrator profile we do not have such problems.

I have also tried to dig into the Session Settings, but they are even looser than on dx orgs.

For the note, we initialize this way:

```
public static final String API_ENDPOINT = Url.getOrgDomainUrl().toExternalForm() + '/services/Soap/m/' + MetadataHelper.METADATA_VERSION;
/*...*/
MetadataService.MetadataPort service = new MetadataService.MetadataPort();
service.SessionHeader = new MetadataService.SessionHeader_element();
service.SessionHeader.sessionId = UserInfo.getSessionId();
service.CallOptions = new MetadataService.CallOptions_element();
service.timeout_x = 120000;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me this have resolved the issue:

Go to the user's profile (in my case System Administrator) -> Edit ->
set `Session Security Level Required at Login` to `None`
-> Save.

Somehow, if it is `High Assurance`, session id in async jobs isn't valid for API usage.

Link to helpful article: https://www.infallibletechie.com/2021/11/invalidsessionid-this-session-is-not.html

**UPDATE**:

If even that's not helping, try adding `Use Any API Client` permission through the permission set (not every org has this permission).

**UPDATE 2**:

If even that's not helping, try disabling Setup -> Session Settings -> `Lock sessions to the IP address from which they originated`.

Answer (score 0):

A way of fixing this it is to send the session id `UserInfo.getSessionId()` as a parameter when you invoke/queue your job.

On Anonymous Execution:

```
String sessionId = UserInfo.getSessionId();
ID jobID = System.enqueueJob(new MyServiceJob(sessionId);
```

MyServiceJob:

```
public with sharing class MyServiceJob implements Queueable, Database.AllowsCallouts {
        private String mySessionId;
            
        public MyServiceJob(String sessionId) {
                this.mySessionId = sessionId;
        }
                
        public void execute(System.QueueableContext qc) {
                MetadataService.MetadataPort service = new   MetadataService.MetadataPort();
                service.SessionHeader = new MetadataService.SessionHeader_element();
                service.SessionHeader.sessionId = this.mySessionId;
                service.CallOptions = new MetadataService.CallOptions_element();
                service.timeout_x = 120000;
        }
}
```

As per [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_userinfo.htm#apex_System_UserInfo_getSessionId):

*You can use `getSessionId()` both synchronously and asynchronously. In asynchronous Apex (Batch, Future, Queueable, or Scheduled Apex), this method returns the session ID only when the code is run by an active, valid user. When the code is run by an internal user, such as the automated process user or a proxy user, the method returns `null`.*

Comment: You can use async session in api callouts too, it just should satisfy the conditions I listed in my answer.

Comment: About your answer there is a possible problem. Let's consider the case with batch job with a huge load. It may be running for hours. You pass the session id in constructor. Which means it can expire before the job is finished and lots of batches will just fail because of it. @FabioFarath